# Converting pixels into percentages using CSS

Tags: css, html, pixel

I have a *rectangle*, the width is `125px` and the height is `48px`. I am trying to make the *rectangle* **5% bigger**. How can I get increase the rectangle by **5%**, while knowing the width and height in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS's [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function is your friend:

```
.rect {
    width: calc(125px * 105%);
    height: calc(48px * 105%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#rectangle {
  height: 48px;
  width: 125px;
  background: red;
}

#bigger-rectangle {
  height: calc(48px * 1.05);
  width: calc(125px * 1.05);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
<div id="bigger-rectangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be the use of **[Transform - Scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)**

> 5%  will be 1.05

```css
div {
  line-height:48px;
  background:yellow;
  border:thin dotted black;
  text-align:center;
  width:125px;
  height:48px;
}
.five {
  transform:scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div>125px</div>
<div class="five">5% +</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

125 * 1.05 and 48 * 1.05 in your calculator?